# How does Ubuntu One deal with files changed on more than one computer?

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one

What happens if I edit a file on my desktop PC, and edit the same file on my synchronised laptop which is currently not connected to the internet?

Let's say I have a file called "jobs.todo" in "~/Ubuntu One" on my desktop, and this contains the following:

*Job 1: description

Job 2: description

Job 3: description*

As I have my laptop connected to the internet, this file will appear on both computers.

I disconnect my laptop, and take it away with me on a journey. While I'm away, I think of another job I have to get done and add it to the file, which will now read:

*Job 1: description

Job 2: description

Job 3: description

Job 4: description*

When I get home, I go back to my desktop and think of something else I need to get done, so I add this to the desktop computer's "jobs.todo" file, forgetting that I'd already altered this file on the laptop.

This file will read:

*Job 1: description

Job 2: description

Job 3: description

Job 5: description*

and the file will be synchronised with the cloud soon afterwards, because the desktop machine is connected to the internet.

Some while later, I start up my laptop, it connects itself to the internet wirelessly, and synchronisation with the cloud takes place.

I suspect that the desktop version (with Job 5 in it) will be copied from the cloud, and I will lose the file containing Job 4, because the datestamp on the cloud's version of the file will be later than that on the laptop

Answer (score 4):

What will happen is that when the laptop goes online, the server will tell it it has a new version of the file, and client (specifically `syncdaemon`) will notice it has a new version of the file also. This is called a *conflict*, and resolution is up to the client; what `syncdaemon` does is rename the locally-changed file to `originalname.u1conflict`, and download the file from the server to the original name. If `.u1conflict` already exists, it will try with `.u1conflict.1`, `.u1conflict.2`, and so on.

Right now nothing lets you know about the conflict; for 11.04 we'll be letting you know when they happen, and at some point (but not for 11.04) we'll be creating a little app that will help you resolve the conflicts. There isn't an automatic way of doing it, but we should be able to make it easy / userfriendly.