# ubuntu won't load in dual boot with windows 10 in Uefi mode

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have a laptop with a pre-installed Windows 10. I wanted to switch to ubuntu, but I decided to leave windows installed in case ubuntu's installation doesn't work. So I created a new partition and installed ubuntu 16 LTS on it in uefi mode, using a live USB made by Rufus.
Ubuntu was installed successfully and restarted. But Windows quickly loaded as if nothing happened. And I can't access Ubuntu. Even by holding Shift+Restart and chosing Ubuntu.

I tried every solution I found especially those mentionned in :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/22183...s-10-with-uefi

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

I used the command bcdedit to set the path to ubuntu

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {11e89e34-0792-11e6-bec9-91b447580268}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30


Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {11e89e36-0792-11e6-bec9-91b447580268}
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {11e89e34-0792-11e6-bec9-91b447580268}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

I started Live CD version of ubuntu to copy shimx64.efi to /EFI/Boot and /EFI/Microsoft/Boot and renamed it to Bootx64.efi and Bootmgfw.efi using a Terminal. And when I restarted, nothing happened and I got this error :

```
Insert system disk in drive,
Press any key when ready....
```

Then I restored back the boot files, and retried with Boot-Repair's recommended repair. Restarted, and I got the same previous error...

I also can't choose ubuntu to boot first from Uefi boot in bios setting, as I find only HDD/SSD, USB memory, ODD, LAN1, LAN2 ....
Same when executing the command efibootmgr .

Please help me. I wasted an entire day trying differents solutions as nothing seem to work out for me.

Computer infos:

```
Toshiba Portege R930 series
Os : Windows 10
UEFI boot with secure boot
Intel Rapid Start
SSD 256 Go
```

Comment: randomly, perhaps try "legacy" rather than UEFI from the BIOS.  Wild guess, HTH.  Also, there's a "super grub disk" utility which looks quite useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Among many solutions this is the solution that worked for me :

- Start LiveCD Ubuntu
- Open a new terminal and download Boot-Repair.
- Start Boot-Repair > Advanced Options > Uncheck "Secure boot" in Grub Options > start the repair.
- Reboot PC > access Bios setting > deactivate Secure boot.